# How to sort an alphanumeric listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, sorting, listbox

I have a listbox with list item values like B1, B2,...B7000...etc. Everytime when items get appended to the listbox, I need to sort the whole listbox.

At the moment, they are sorted in this way B1, B100, B1000, B2, B200 etc which is not logical.

How can I sort so that it is like B1, B2, B3....?

I've been trying to use LINQ but it doesn't work:

```
List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>(ListBox7.Items.Cast<ListItem>());
list = list.OrderBy(li => li.Text).ToList<ListItem>();
ListBox7.Items.Clear();
ListBox7.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray<ListItem>());
```

Please help! I've looked everywhere and could not find a solution!

Comment: Do not *sort*.  You need to select a position to append or insert an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var list = listBox.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
            .OrderBy(item => int.Parse(item.Text.TrimStart('B')));

listBox.Items.Clear();
listBox.Items.AddRange(list.ToArray());
```

Comment: thank you soooo much, really appreciate it! spent so much time on it - didn't know it was that simple!

Comment: may I ask, say if I need to only order the items beginning with B and ignore other ones, how would I write that?
i.e. TrimStart('B') all the items beginning with B but ignore ones beginning with say 'D'. (Because atm, it will fail if it tries to TrimStart non-B items. Thanks!!!